# How to select a part of a land cover type a certain amount of feet away from another land cover type

Tags: raster, raster-calculator, analysis, land-cover

I have raster Landcover type Urban combined with Forest all within the county raster perimeter. I want to make a layer of only the forest cells that are more than 500 feet from an urban cell, so that all forest cells that share space with urban less than 500 ft are removed.I suppose I need to create a grid of distance from urban land, but I don't know how to input "from" into a raster calculator operation.

[image: Euclidean distance of urban features]

[image: combine of urban and forest/shrub features]

I want the forest/shrub that is more than 500 feet from urban land

Comment: Have you looked into the [distance tools](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/An_overview_of_the_Distance_tools/009z00000014000000/)?

Comment: Yes, and I've included screen shots, the first is eucl. dist. of urban land and the second is the combined features of urban and forest/shrub land

Answer (score 2):

Given the Euclidean distance from urban areas, for instance you can reclassify it (0 for distance <= 50 ft, 1 elsewhere) using the Reclassify tool. (Alternatively, you can apply an equivalent conditional expression with the Raster Calculator... So you can choose the way you like). Then you should simply multiply the reclassified Euclidean distance with the (combined) Land Cover raster using the Raster Calculator. In detail, all the cells whose value is different from 0 will be the *"forest/shrub that is more than 500 feet from urban land"* you need.